# Change characters typed on TextEditor in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I'm trying to capture the text typed in a TextEditor, store it in a variable and update what is displayed on the TextEditor itself. I'm using the `.onChange()` to trigger and capture what is being typed, store it in a variable, and change the current text being displayed. But the problem is that, `.onChange()` is being called twice: First, when i type the text inside the TextEditor; and Second, when i try to set a different character for the view itself.

```
struct ChatView: View {
    @State var chatTextInput: String = ""
    @State var oldChatValue: String = ""
    @State var newChatValue: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $chatTextInput)
                .onChange(of: chatTextInput) { newValue in
                    oldChatValue += "a"
                    newChatValue += newValue.last.map{String($0)}!
                    chatTextInput = oldChatValue
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

For exemple, if i type **qwerty**, `newChatValue` is printed as *Qawaearataya* and `chatTextInput` receives *aaaaaaaaaaaa*

Any clues on how to prevent the .onChange to being triggered the second time, when i set the new character for the TextEditor text?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might be better off explaining exactly what you are want to do... Are you trying to insert "a" between each character typed?

Comment: Or... do you want "a" to be shown regardless of what's typed? So, for example, as you type "qwerty" you want the text editor to show "aaaaaa" and `newChatValue` should then contain "qwerty"?

Comment: @DonMag Yeah,  sorry if i wasn't clear enough. What i'm trying is exactly what you said. I want to "a" replace whatever the user types in the TextEditor. And `newChatValue` should store what was typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is simply that `.onChange(of:)` isn't a responder to the `TextEditor`, it is a responder for the variable, in this case `chatTextInput`. Since `chatTextInput` is bound to the `TextEditor`, when you type a letter, `chatTextInput` is updated, and `.onChange(of:)` runs. However, as part of `.onChange(of:)` running, you change `chatTextInput` which calls `.onChange(of:) again. You would have an infinite loop, except that` .onChange(of:)` ends at this point. If anyone can explain that, I would love to hear it.

The fix, however is to simply put a flag in `.onChange(of:)` to only set the variables every other time like this:

```
struct ChatView: View {
    @State var chatTextInput: String = ""
    @State var oldChatValue: String = ""
    @State var newChatValue: String = ""
    
    @State var textEntryFlag = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $chatTextInput)
                .onChange(of: chatTextInput) { newValue in
                    if textEntryFlag {
                        oldChatValue += "a"
                        newChatValue += newValue.last.map{String($0)}!
                        chatTextInput = oldChatValue
                    }
                    textEntryFlag.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very simple and did the trick!! Do you know if there's any other way to solve this without using `.onChange()`, that acts as responder directly to the TextEditor?

Comment: There is nothing else for `TextEditor`. For `TextField` you have `.onSubmit(of:)`, but it currently doesn't exist for `TextEditor`.

Comment: That was what i suspected. Anyway, thanks again for your help!